# How do I return another word from an array if it is called by a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I created a function called appearance() where it will return a random word from my array and store it into the console log and I called it again when the user correctly writes the prompt it will change to another. However, the issue I am having is the the function will not return another word except the first loaded prompt. It will only change the inner.html What might the steps or logic be to create another function that would return another item from the array into the console instead of just appearing physically on the screen.

```js
var dancelist = ["Merengue", "Bachata", "Samba", "Mambo", "Tango", "Salsa", "Flamenco", "Paso Doble", "Reggaeton", "Bomba", "Kizomba", "Bolero"] ;

function appearance(){
  var randomWord = dancelist[Math.floor(Math.random() * dancelist.length)];
  dancenames.innerHTML = randomWord;
  return randomWord;
}

 function matchAnswerWord(){
    if (word.join('') == danceChar){
      console.log("yes it is");
      appearance();
    }
    
    if(danceChar[entryCount-1] == char){
      console.log("it's working");
      dancenames.style.color = "#FD005B";
    } else {
      console.log("it's notworking");
      dancenames.style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
```

https://codepen.io/bugarte/pen/abOwOgw?editors=0011

Comment: Now that is a dramatic refactor of epic proportions! Well done, sir (or madame)!  +❶

Comment: I managed to fix the issue pushing the words into a string except now I don't know why the text is changing blue even though the individual character matches the prompt. Hence pink when right and blue when correct. https://codepen.io/bugarte/pen/jOPwzNO?editors=0011